# SQL Query Problems With Counting Frequency

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been trying to list all yelp users who haven't reviewed any businesses but have provided at least 2 comments on other user's reviews for the following table:[image]

[image]

But I've been having some issues.  These issues mainly are derived from my attempts to count the elements listed as a varchar.  For example, the questions states that I need to return users who have commented on atleast two other user's reviews.  Currently I have the List_Of_Comments stored as a varchar with the characters looking like the following: "Y3, Y2".  How am I supposed to determine how often a user posts a comment through a varchar?This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT U.YELP_ID FROM REVIEWS R, YELP_USER U 
WHERE R.Author = U.YELP_ID AND R.Author = NULL AND R.Number_Of_Comments >= 2;
```

Assuming the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE REVIEWS (
REVIEW_ID VARCHAR(3),
Stars INT,
Author VARCHAR(3),
Publish_Date VARCHAR(22),
BUSSINESS_ID VARCHAR(3),
List_Of_Comments VARCHAR(7),
Number_Of_Comments INT
);

CREATE TABLE YELP_USER (
YELP_ID VARCHAR(3),
Email VARCHAR(17),
First_Name VARCHAR(8),
Last_Name VARCHAR(17),
DOB DATE,
BirthPlace VARCHAR(3),
Gender VARCHAR(1),
Friendlist VARCHAR(9),
Complimented_Friendlist VARCHAR(6),
Checkedin_Businesses VARCHAR(36)
);
```

If anyone could help me figure this out I would greatly appreciate it.  I've been stuck on this for hours.  Thanks!

Comment: so...mysql, SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: Your data structure is very troublesome. You seem to have delimited values in several of your columns. This violates 1NF and is a serious pain to deal with. Of course, the sizes of those columns hinder putting any real quantity of information there anyway.

Comment: Sorry it's Oracle SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer what I think you are asking... How to count the number of entries in a comma separated list:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
INSERT INTO REVIEWS VALUES ( 1, 1, 'A1', DATE '2016-02-02', 'B1', 'C1,C2', NULL );
INSERT INTO REVIEWS VALUES ( 2, 1, 'A2', DATE '2016-02-01', 'B1', 'C3', NULL );
INSERT INTO REVIEWS VALUES ( 3, 1, 'A3', DATE '2016-02-01', 'B1', NULL, NULL );
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT REVIEW_ID,
       COALESCE( REGEXP_COUNT( List_of_comments, '[^,]+' ), 0 ) AS Number_of_comments
FROM   REVIEWS;
```

**Results**:

```
REVIEW_ID NUMBER_OF_COMMENTS
--------- ------------------
1                          2 
2                          1 
3                          0
```

**A better solution**:

Storing it how you are doing with a `VARCHAR2(7)` column for a list of comments will only allow you to store, at most, 4 comment IDs (if each ID is a single character).

It would be better to move them to their own tables using something like:

```
CREATE TABLE REVIEW_COMMENTS (
  COMMENT_ID    NUMBER(8,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  REVIEW_ID     VARCHAR2(3) REFERENCES REVIEWS( REVIEW_ID ),
  YELP_ID       VARCHAR2(3) REFERENCES YELP_USER( YELP_ID ),
  COMMENT_VALUE VARCHAR2(140)
);

COMMENT ON TABLE REVIEW_COMMENTS IS 'The comments on a review by a user.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN REVIEW_COMMENTS( COMMENT_ID ) IS 'A unique identifier for the comment by a user on a review.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN REVIEW_COMMENTS( REVIEW_ID ) IS 'The identifier for the review the comment was left against.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN REVIEW_COMMENTS( YELP_ID ) IS 'The identifier for the user who left the comment.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN REVIEW_COMMENTS( COMMENT_VALUE ) IS 'The text of the comment.';
```

Also, do not store dates as `VARCHAR2` column.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure only allows 2 comments for each review (at least 2 chars for each review, plus two commas. Any other comment will not fit in 7 chars), but assuming that's what you want, you could try to get all the users that are not in the review table

```
... from yelp_users yu 
where not exists in (select 1 from reviews r where r.author = yu.yelp_id)
```

and his id is on the list of comments. I would search it using instr:

```
and exists (
    select 1 
    from reviews r 
    where instr(',' || r.list_of_comments || ',', ',' || yu.yelp_id || ',' , 1, 1) > 0)
```

I've concatenated ',' to avoid you the case where you look for Y1 and end up getting a false positive when Y11 is the one that commented.

As your goal is to get users who commented at least twice, you could move the review table to from and put all the SQL in a subquery, grouping the user id on the external SQL.
=)